# Set background color for row-fluid bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the code for a simple data table with some pagination controls styled using bootstrap, and datatables for the grid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page, using dataTables</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <style>
  div.dataTables_info{
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }

  #id1{
    background-color: lightblue !important;
  }

  div.panel-body{
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
              Titulo tabela
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
              <table id="tabela" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Value 1</td>
                    <td>Value 2</td>
                    <td>Value 3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Valor 1</td>
                    <td>Valor 2</td>
                    <td>Valor 3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Value 4</td>
                    <td>Value 5</td>
                    <td>Value 6</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/ColReorderWithResize.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function(){
        $('#tabela').DataTable({
          "dom": 'Rrt<"row-fluid"<"#id1"<"#a.col-md-4"i><"col-md-4"l><"#b.col-md-4"p>>>'
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jose_ramirez/tnoefud0/2/) of the code above, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jose_ramirez/tnoefud0/2/embedded/result) the result in fullscreen.

The thing is that for desktop-type screens, when in fullscreen the bottom row containing the pagination controls loses the background color. Is there some way of keeping the background for all screen widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you lose the background is that, on large screens, the contents of `#id1` is floated.

You can put a *clearfix* like this:

```
#id1:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tnoefud0/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap comes with a `clearfix`. A clearfix is used when a parent element contains floated child elements and you want the parent element to take up the content area of the child elements.

Change  this:

```
<div id="id1">
```

to this:

```
<div id="id1" class="clearfix">
```

The `.col-md-4` elements are floated to the left. When an element is floated it is taken out of the normal document flow which means, as far as a parent element is concerned, the child elements will not take up any space. So the parent element will have a height of none as the child elements are not taking up any space and as a result you cannot see you background color anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*add*/
table.dataTable{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
#id1{
    background-color: lightblue !important;
    overflow:hidden; /*add*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnoefud0/4/

Look this code.
Add overflow for your id1 and delete bottom margin for table.